# Using file list in javascript for multiple drag and drop

Tags: javascript

I have a simple drag and drop page in my website. It allows dragging and dropping files, and below code gives me a list of dropped files.

`var files = e.target.files || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);`

So far, so good. Problem is that when I drag and drop more files, that files object will not append to list of files I already had. Say, I dropped 2 files for the first time. files variable has 2 files in that case. If I drop a third file, `e.target.files` will have only the third file.

I tried creating a global variable and doing `+=` to append file list. But javascript treats that variable as a string by default. So, `var selectedFiles += e.target.files` treats the file list as a string.

How can I make it so I have a list of files appended everytime a file is dropped?

Comment: I doubt that `e.target.files` is a string - rather a list. So you would have to push (`array.push()`) each single file in files to your own list each time.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me figure it out. I was declaring variable as `var selectedFileList;` instead of `var selectedFileList = [];`. That's why it was considering the variable as string. Updated declaration and used push instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Created a page level variable like so.

`var selectedFiles = [];`

And then used below code to push the files to this list.

```
var files = e.target.files || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);
//Loop through all dropped files
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //Add files to the selected file list
    selectedFiles.push(files[i]);
}
```

There is unnecessary looping, but I guess I can't fix that problem just yet.

Comment: Depending on your browser support `selectedFiles.push(...files)` could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push each single file to your own list (`array`). MDN has a nice example for it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop

```js
var _Files = [];

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(ev) {
  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();

  if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
      // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
      if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
        var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
        _Files.push(file)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      _Files.push(files[i])
    }
  };

  console.log(_Files)
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
  <p>Drag one or more files to this Drop Zone ...</p>
</div>
```